# remove "latest files" from Drupal module FileDepot

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

How can I prevent the Drupal module "FileDepot" from displaying "latest files" when a user first enters file depot?

Is is possible to have it display nothing until a user clicks on a folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `sites/all/modules/filedepot/lib-ajaxserver.php` I added `1=2 and`  to sql you may check it with your original one.
it worked for me

```
// Default view - latest files
if (!empty($filedepot->allowableViewFoldersSql)) {
  if ($filedepot->ogmode_enabled) {
    if (!empty($filedepot->allowableGroupViewFoldersSql)) {
      $sql .= "WHERE 1=2 and file.cid in ({$filedepot->allowableGroupViewFoldersSql}) ";
    }
    else {
      $sql .= "WHERE 1=2 and file.cid in ({$filedepot->allowableViewFoldersSql}) ";
    }
  }
  elseif (!user_access('administer filedepot', $user)) {
    if (empty($filedepot->allowableViewFoldersSql)) {
      $sql .= "WHERE 1=2 and file.cid is NULL ";
    }
    else {
      $sql .= "WHERE 1=2 and file.cid in ({$filedepot->allowableViewFoldersSql}) ";
    }
  }
}
```